# Decent Node.js library for server workload testing

Tags: node.js, testing

I'm about to develop a web app so i tought i could test the workload with a single Node client since it can make multiple calls to the server without blocking.

Looking at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules, in the testing section i foun plenty of frameworks, and my question is if someone can recommend or has heard good things from any of those.

I think this is a perfectly answer question, that's why im asking it here.

**Edit:**
The idea is to use node on the client side not the server that serves the webapp, so profiling would be out of scope when it comes to decide what node testing framework to use.

Comment: https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload

Comment: What statistics are you hoping to gather?  Do you need to know throughput, latency, etc?  or are you more interested in profiling the application to find out where it spends its time?